# Passing in arguments to py::exec

Tags: pybind11

I would like to evaluate a Python expression in C++ using Pybind11. This expression is quite simple:

```
arr = np.asarray(arg, copy = False)
f(arr)
```

where `f` is an object instance with a `__call__` method, and `arg` is some object that is compatible with np copying, like a `py::buffer_info`.

I have successfully generated `f` and `arg` in C++ as objects. I would now like to call them in Python somehow. I imagine this involves using `py::eval` or `py::exec`, but I'm not sure how to do this using arguments. [The examples listed](https://extractor(data)) in the docs seem to point to using dictionaries to pass in as objects in, and then receiving the output as a dictionary:

```
auto locals = py::dict("name"_a="World", "number"_a=42);
    py::exec(R"(
        message = "Hello, {name}! The answer is {number}".format(**locals())
    )", py::globals(), locals);

    auto message = locals["message"].cast<std::string>();
```

but I'm not sure if there's a more efficient way.

Comment: [Hint](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#_CPPv4I_19return_value_policyDpENK10object_apiclE6objectDpRR4Args) -- once you have them held by `pybind11:::object` or one of the other related classes, it should be as simple as `f(arr)`. on the C++ side as well. IIRC `py::array` has a constructor that takes `py::buffer_info`. There really should be no need for `eval` or `exec`. If you replace the prose that describes the current situation with a proper [mcve], I can try to put together a concrete code example (right now there's a bit too much guessing involved).